# Rewrite Rule Issues

Tags: php, regex, apache, mod-rewrite, silverstripe

I hate to write this post but i've been working on this for far too long.
We are upgrading a multilingual site and the language module that we are now using handles URL's very differently. We are moving from `domain.com/location-fr-fr/` to `domain.com/fr_FR/location/`. I have been able successfully handle rewriting that by using the following `RewriteRule (.*)-fr-fr fr_FR/$1/`. I  cannot figure out the english one which looks like this. `domain.com/location/` has to go to `domain.com/en_US/location/`

Where im running into the issue is I can't just rewrite everything, as I need to exclude any url beginning with /en_US or /fr_FR, but im failing with that.

I have tried this which i really think should work

```
RewriteRule ^(?!en_US/) http://www.google.com
```

I tried adding in a preceding slash but no good either

```
RewriteRule ^(?!/en_US/) http://www.google.com
```

https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ agrees with me that it should work too but in practice it does not. I have been doing all my testing using wget so that browser caching is not an issue.
Can someone give me a couple of pointers? I'm open to any suggestions on how to make this work better. 
It's a Silverstripe website in case that affects rewrites too.

**Edit:**
After removing Silverstripe rewrite rules the rule works fine.

Comment: Did you look at [the documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule)? "In mod_rewrite, the NOT character ('!') is also available as a possible pattern prefix. This enables you to negate a pattern..."

Comment: In any case, this is off-topic  – it's not a programming question but a server configuration problem.